# How to prevent older builds from entering stage with concurrency 1

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

We've setup a Jenkins build pipeline that uses Maven to build a large project, including stages for update, compile, unit test and deploy (to Nexus). The "deploy to Nexus" stage has concurrency 1 to ensure that no more than one build is in this stage at any point in time. However, this setting does not prevent older builds from entering that stage after a later build has finished it.

For instance, if build #2 is startet after build #1 and hits a fast node, it may outrun build #1 and enter the "deploy to Nexus" stage first. Build #1 cannot enter this stage at the same time, so it waits until build #2 is finished; but then build #1 enters this stage and thus overrides the Maven artifacts deployed by the later build, which is not what you want.

There must be a way to avoid this, i.e. to prevent older builds from entering a stage that was already executed successfully by later builds. I just could not find a solution for this problem... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The [upcoming](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-milestone-step-plugin/pull/1) `milestone` step is supposed to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Send the current build number of the job and add a simple condition to test it with the latest successful build number of the job using the following Jenkins URL:

http://JenkinsMaster:Port/job/MyJob/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber

If the current build number is smaller than the last successful one then skip the upload.

Good Luck!